# How to customize scrolling animation Flip page, Depth page transformer on Folio Reader Epub

Tags: android, flutter

I want to customize **Flip Page, Depth page transformer scrolling** when horizontal in Epub Folio reader library, I added transition animation to ViewPage but some pages still not working, it't still slide.

Folio library use: https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android

Here is a video : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bubsrpmJEun6qj7YupBFu60kUtGNd85F/view?usp=sharing

Can you help my with my code? => https://github.com/mhungo/epub_demo.git

**I try to set tranformer for ViewPager:
**

```
class DepthPageTransformer : DirectionalViewpager.PageTransformer {

    override fun transformPage(view: View, position: Float) {
        view.apply {
            val pageWidth = width
            when {
                position < -1 -> { // [-Infinity,-1)
                    // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                    alpha = 0f
                }
                position <= 0 -> { // [-1,0]
                    // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page.
                    alpha = 1f
                    translationX = 0f
                    translationZ = 0f
                    scaleX = 1f
                    scaleY = 1f
                }
                position <= 1 -> { // (0,1]
                    // Fade the page out.
                    alpha = 1 - position

                    // Counteract the default slide transition.
                    translationX = pageWidth * -position
                    // Move it behind the left page.
                    translationZ = -1f

                    // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1).
                    val scaleFactor = ((0.75f + ((1 - 0.75f) * (1 - Math.abs(position)))))
                    scaleX = scaleFactor
                    scaleY = scaleFactor
                }
                else -> { // (1,+Infinity]
                    // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                    alpha = 0f
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---- FolioActivity ----

```
mFolioPageViewPager!!.setPageTransformer(true, DepthPageTransformer())
```

---- FolioActivity ----

My expectation is that all pages have scrollable animations and not slide